# Representing 3-dimensional lines with a single Cartesian equation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I know that a [3-dimensional line can be represented by a symmetric equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87505/equation-for-a-straight-line-in-cartesian-space) - for example:

$$\frac{x-x_p}{x_q-x_p}=\frac{y-y_p}{y_q-y_p}=\frac{z-z_p}{z_q-z_p}$$

Why is this not written as a single equation, such as:

$$2\frac{x-x_p}{x_q-x_p}-\frac{y-y_p}{y_q-y_p}-\frac{z-z_p}{z_q-z_p} = 0$$

Comment: These are not equivalent. The formula below is always true if the above formula is true, but not the other way around.

Comment: Your equation defines a plane not a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any equation written as you have in the second equation defines a plane. What you have can be reduced to:
$$c_1*x+c_2*y+c_3*z=c_4$$
where the $c$s are constants. In fact, you have three equations in the first equation and one in the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

An example may help: take $x_p = y_p = z_p = 0,$ but  $x_q = y_q = z_q = 1.$ The line in question is
$$  x = y = z.  $$ This is a line that goes through the origin $(0,0,0),$ and the point $(1,1,1).$

Your revision becomes $$ 2x - y - z = 0.  $$
This plane passes though the origin $(0,0,0),$ and the point $(1,1,1),$ but it also passes through $(1,0,2).$ The line does not do that.