# Ratio of coordinate

Tags: 3d

[image]

In the above question, how have they written the ratio given in the first step of solution?

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87505/equation-for-a-straight-line-in-cartesian-space) for the equation of a line in space.

Answer (score 0):

As both the points P and Q lie on the same line .

That's why their ratio is constant .