# how to convert from parametric to explicit formula?

Tags: linear-algebra

In stereographic projection map, o is the "North pole" (0, 0, -1). 
Find a parametric equation for the line between o and v = (x, y, z).

$\vec{ov}$ = (x, y, z)-(0, 0, -1) = $< x , y ,z + 1 >$
$r(t)= <0, 0, -1> + t< x , y ,z + 1 >$
$r(t) = < tx,ty,-z-1>$

Is the answer above correct?

Then how do I convert this into an explicit formula? or what does an explicit formula mean?

Comment: I removed the graph theory tag since this question doesn't seem to pertain to graph theory (at least not in any obvious way).

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87515/435819) to a similar question.